How are these measurements mathematically possible?
I just created this shape by extruding from a vertex, and the edges that are along the X and Y axes are all correct and symmetrical, but the diagonals are somehow ending up with different lengths according to the Measure tool. I just double-checked, and all of the vertices are aligned on the Z axis and symmetrical on the X axis, so I don't understand how this is mathematically possible. What am I missing here?


Short version, it isn't. Since this geometry is not centered on the object origin, it's not clear how you verified that it was symmetrical. Most likely you made a mistake.

UPDATE: All of the vertices are aligned on the Z axis (I verified this by selecting all vertices and scaling by 0), and the 2 edges along the X axis both measure 9.805 mm, but when I select a vertex on one of those edges and snap it along the X axis to the vertex that should be parallel to it, it does move (causing the two edges to no longer measure as the same length).

Most likely float-point precision issues

@KevinFrederickSmith can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com.

@HarryMcKenzie We don't need the file. The shape is not symmetrical, you can even see it with the naked eye looking at the grid in the screenshot.

Just in case you didn't notice: the shape in the screenshot is definitely not symmetrical. The shorter edge on the right with a length of 19.589 seems to be perfectly vertical, the long one on the left with 47.922 is not vertical. The top corner lies on the grid vertical, the bottom corner is left of the grid. So when the horizontal lines are both the same size, the bottom one is further left, so the lower diagonal one has to be longer to connect to it. I guess that's really all there is to it.


I missed that. I thought that I had looked closely at it, but it turns not quite closely enough. : )
